# Regular expression validator for name which allows charactors, numbers,slash,hyphen,space but not allow only numbers and other speacial characters

Tags: asp.net

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{2,50}$
```

Iam trying for a regax allowing both numbers and alphabets with space,hyphen,slash for name without allowing only numbers and also not allowing special characters

Comment: Which is it to be? C# or Classic?

Answer (score 1):

Something like so seems to work for me: `^([0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9'@&#.\s\/-]*)$`. You could then use the `.Length` property to ensure that the length is within the expected value.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/sL2pK9/4).

Comment: sorry now my question changed

Comment: @ShamilKhan: Please provide some information as to why the answer above does not suit your needs.

Comment: above answer not allowing slash and hyphen ,but i need a regex which allows the mixture of character,numbers,white space,slash,hyphen.But which will not allow only numbers and other special characters.Also its length between  2 to 50

Comment: @ShamilKhan: I have updaed my answer. The regex assumes that you need to at least 1 letter and that the string does not start with special characters.

Comment: Sorry man..Its not working ,its allowing @& special characters..I cleared the length issue..but still not working ..

Comment: @ShamilKhan: Those are part of the regular expression you have posted, which is why I assumed you wanted them around.